# combine 2 tables and aggregate data

Tags: python, mysql, aggregate

users

Could you please help with following?

I need to extract data from a mysql database and aggregate them.
There are two tables in the database, both of them have data in a dfferent timestep.
I need now to make one new table (txt), where all data of table 1 are combined with table 2 data.
I so only need the data of table 2 with most coresponding time to timesteps of table 1.

for better understanding, see an example of the tables here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mo2q0hj72ilx05n/data%20aggregation.xlsx?dl=0

I already have a python-code which extracts the hexadecimal data and makes table 2.
I also have a code which makes table 1.
I need to combine both now.

Thank you very much for your advices!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this. Please also avoid linking to offsite resources.

Answer (score 0):

After copying your data tables into Python lists, I had to split up the values in table 2 back into independent series. Overall you may be able to skip the step where you consolidate these values into the single table Table2.

The key to solving this is to write a simple class that implements `__getitem__`, taking a single key argument and returning the corresponding value. For instance, in the case of a regular Python dict, then `__getitem__` returns the dict entry that exactly matches the key, or a KeyError if there is no match. In your case, I implemented `__getitem__` to just return the entry with the minimum difference of the entry's timestamp from the given timestamp, in this line:

```
closest = min(self.data, key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-keyts))
```

(Left as an exercise to the OP - how to handle the case where the key falls exactly between two entries.) If you need to adjust the lookup logic, just change the implementation of `__getitem__` - everything else in the code will remain the same.

Here is my sample implementation:

```
# t1 and t2 are lists of tab-delimited strings copy-pasted 
# from the OP's spreadsheet

TAB = '\t'
t1data = [t.split(TAB) for t in t1]
t2data = [t.split(TAB) for t in t2]

# split each parameter into individual time,value pairs
readings = {'A':[], 'B':[], 'C':[]}
for parm in "ABC":
    for trec in t2data:
        t,a,b,c = trec
        t = int(t)
        if a: readings['A'].append((t,int(a)))
        if b: readings['B'].append((t,int(b)))
        if c: readings['C'].append((t,int(c)))


# define class for retrieving value with "closest" key if
# there is not an exact match
class LookupClosest(object):

    def __init__(self, pairs):
        self.data = pairs

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # implement logic here to find closest matching item in series

        # TODO - what if key is exactly between two different values?
        closest = min(self.data, key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-key))
        return closest[1]


# convert each data series to LookupClosest
for key in "ABC":
    readings[key] = LookupClosest(readings[key])

# extract and display data
for vals in t1data:
    t = int(vals[0])
    gps = vals[1]
    a = readings['A'][t]
    b = readings['B'][t]
    c = readings['C'][t]
    rec = t,gps,a,b,c
    print rec
```

prints: (I modified the Table1 data so that you can tell the difference from one record to the next):

```
( 1, 'x01', 1, 10, 44)
(10, 'x10', 2, 11, 47)
(21, 'x21', 4, 12, 45)
(30, 'x30', 3, 12, 44)
(41, 'x41', 4, 12, 47)
(52, 'x52', 2, 10, 48)
```